# How do I get a div to be seperated 10% from the right and left side of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I was inspecting the pages of websites that achieve this functionality, and must of them have this achieved by adding right and left margins. However when I add this functionality for testing purposes my div goes off the screen.

For example,

```
#test {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

  <div id="test">



  </div>
```

Goes right off the screen instead of being 10% from both the right and left sides of the screen.

How can this functionality be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margins, you could set a padding to the parent div (or the body in this case).

```css
body {
  padding: 0 10%
}

#test {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the `width` to **80%**.

When you set `margin-right/left` to 10% each and width 100%, that's more than 100% in total, thus exceeding the div goes off the screen.

You can try the following:

```
#test {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```